# rapid miner: how to add a 'label' attribute to a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree, rapidminer

I want to apply a decision tree learning algorithm to a dataset I have imported from a CSV.
The problem is that the "tra" input of the Decision Tree block is still red, stating "Input example set must have special attribute 'label'.".
How do I add that label? What is it?
I have been playing around with it for some time without results. Any help appreciated.

ADDENDUM: the column's titles have been correctly inferred, so I have no clue on what the 'label' is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Label is the attribute that represents the target class for classification. "Set Role" operator can set an attribute as label, but you can do that when importing the data - most import operators can be configured to set the role of attributes. "Read CSV" is one of them.

Answer (score 13):

When you import data in RapidMiner, In Step number 4, you need to select the attribute type "label" for the column you wish to classify.

[image: Labelling the classifier column as with "label" attribute]

Click Next button in the bottom.

In Step 5, it will ask you to save the import file, Choose any suitable name and click 'Finish'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you suggest is correct, but I actually found more useful Josef Borkovec's answer since it applies to any stage of the computation, and is not limited to the data importation.